# Two-sided tree on d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a Mind Map using D3.
My current task is to make a two-sided tree.

I took  [this](http://bl.ocks.org/jdarling/2d4e84460d5f5df9c0ff) for example. But this one was written using `d3.v3` and I'm using the v5.

The whole layout is computed in this block:

```js
// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodesLeft = tree
  .size([h, (w / 2) - 20])
  .children(function(d) {
    return (d.depth === 0) ? d.left : d.children;
  })
  .nodes(root)
  .reverse();
var nodesRight = tree
  .size([h, w / 2])
  .children(function(d) {
    return (d.depth === 0) ? d.right : d.children;
  })
  .nodes(root)
  .reverse();
root.children = root.left.concat(root.root._children = null;
    var nodes = toArray(root);
```

But I have no idea how to implement this using v5.

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: A v4 implementation is available here: http://thomasrickard.uk/articles/d3---mindmaps-%28v4%29-13-08-2016.html, it needed no changes to port to v5 as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh9q1x8z/2/